# Remember lastly selected radio button on the browser-back button

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, back-button

I got three radio buttons.

> I want the browser to remember the last selected/checked radio button, while I use to navigate through the *browser back button*.

I have already *stored the values in the local storage*.

#### The problem and flow,

- Page A has a radio button (where I have selected 2nd radio button)
- Now I go to another page B
- Lastly, I jump back to page A using browser back button
- Get the result that the 1st radio button is selected

**Want solution on this**: How can I dynamically set something to remember the last click event on the radio buttons?

### HTML

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-10 form-inline justify-content-xl-center">

        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="filterClient" id="filterClientes1" value="activeClient" checked="checked"
                (change)="statusCustomers = '1'">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="filterClient1" i18n="Filter | Customers 
                            filter.@@filter_actives">
                <b>Active Customers</b>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="filterClient" id="filterClient2" value="inactiveClient" (change)="statusCustomers = '0'">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="filterClient2" i18n="Filter | Customers 
                            filter.@@filter_inactives">
                <b>Inactive Customers</b>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="filterClient" id="filterClient3" value="allClient" (change)="statusCustomers = '2'">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="filterClient3" i18n="Filter | Customers 
                            filter.@@filter_all">
                <b>All Customers</b>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### TYPESCRIPT

```
  filterCustomer(fieldValue: string, statusCustomers: string, statusQueries: string) {
// * REMOVE WHEN WE'RE DONE
statusQueries = '1';
this.restartFields();
const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
  customClass: {
    confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
    cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-secondary ml-4'
  },
  buttonsStyling: false
});
this.filteredCustomer = [];
if (fieldValue === '') {
  this.showspinner = false;
  this.searchError = 'You must enter a search';
} else {
  this.searchError = '';
  this.showspinner = true;
  this.customerService.getCustomers(fieldValue, statusCustomers, statusQueries).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      this.nullError = 'No customer related search found';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('filterField', JSON.stringify(fieldValue));
    localStorage.setItem('radiobuttonsCustomers', JSON.stringify(this.statusCustomers));

    data.map(item => {
      this.filteredCustomer.push(item);
      localStorage.setItem('customers', JSON.stringify(this.filteredCustomer));
       });
    this.showspinner = false;
    this.paginationDisplayed = this.filteredCustomer.length > environment.DTSize;
    this.initializeDT();
  }, error => {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
      'Error!',
      'Error Not Applicable.',
      'error'
    );
  });
  this.customers = this.filteredCustomer;
  }
```

}

Comment: You setItem after getting data from customer but where did you get your item from localstorage and then set it to the scope for by default selection radio button?

Answer (score 1):

Before navigating to different page, make sure you store the value into local storage.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    localStorage.setItem("myradio", radiovalue);
}
```

Next : inside document.ready function check for the local storage, if value is there, set it to the radio button.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("myradio") != undefined){
    var myradioValue = localStorage.getItem("myradio")
    $("input[name=input_name][value="+myradioValue+"]").attr('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: I do not get the second part of your solution. Could you please tell me more where the lines of code should be?

Comment: 1.while you navigate from PageA to PageB, store the selected radio button value into local storage. 
2. When you navigate from pageB to pageA, check whether there is localstorage varaiable, if it is there, set the radio button value.

Note : Code which I have written is pure javascript, not the typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You change the state of checked in such a way

```
[checked]="variable_name"
```

here the variable should be boolean.

Also write the below line in ngOnInit in lifecyle hook

```
variable_name = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('fieldName_in_localStorage'))
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahnk5q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts